# Deploying a python/ruby code on a decentralized network

Tags: python, deployment, blockchain

I was studying about DApps and I found most of them are written using Solidity and JS. Also, I found that there's a web3.py library for people who love python (and I didn't search for the same thing in ruby programming language). But, I have a question, is there any decentralized system like heroku? I mean, writing a piece of code (e.g. Sinatra/Flask based API) and then deploy on that network?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're asking:  is there an application that will let me build applications and deploy them to the network?

You might take a look at [Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/).  You can develop and deploy applications in Javascript.

However, if you like Python (like I do), I just released an open source tool called [Ezo](https://github.com/robinagist/ezo). It's in alpha, so patience please.  :)  It's a command-line tool for building off-chain event responders (or oracles) for Ethereum.  [Here's an article on how to use it](https://medium.com/@robinagist/build-an-ethereum-oracle-in-10-minutes-using-ezo-and-python-80627c3909a7).

You'll also want to download and install [Ganache](http://truffleframework.com/ganache/) to simulate a working Ethereum EVM.  You'll likely lean on it a lot during any development you may do.  Good luck.